# Elasticsearch mapping from 2x to 5x

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new in elastic and I have some difficulties to convert a simple mapping from version 2x to version 5x

**Here the mapping**

```
POST movies/movie/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "director": {
      "type": "multi_field",
      "fields": {
        "director": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "original": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here the error I have in 5x version

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "No handler for type [multi_field] declared on field [director]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "No handler for type [multi_field] declared on field [director]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I've try to do this

```
PUT movies/movie/_mapping
{
  "_all": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "director": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

I received an

```
{
  "acknowledged": true
}
```

But it's not working as expected.

The goal is: field director contain "francis ford coppola"

---

Thanks @Val, now I have reindex as the mapping has changed.
But what I want to do is not working properly.

**Here what I want to do**

```
GET movies/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "director": "francis ford coppola"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't have any hits for this one.

I have two hits with:

```
GET movies/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "director": ["francis", "ford", "coppola"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here my current mapping

```
{
  "movies": {
    "mappings": {
      "movie": {
        "properties": {
          "director": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "genres": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "year": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Multi-fields have changed syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/multi-fields.html) between ES2 and ES5. The correct way to do it in ES 5 is as follows:

```
POST movies/movie/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "director": {
      "type": "text"
      "fields": {
        "original": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Val but I still have issues, I have edited my request in order to let you have more informations about my mapping and what I want to do.

Comment: You need to use a `match` query, not a `term` one, simply replace `term` by `match`